# Possible to transfer a large file (approx. 90GB) between a windows PC and a Mac via direct Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mac

Setup:

1. MacBook Pro, connected to guest network (Wi-Fi)
2. Windows laptop, connected to corporate network (Wi-Fi)
3. External 1TB USB3 SSD, formatted in HFS+. Can't change to exFAT, too much data on it.

I need to transfer a 90GB file from [2] to [3]
Is it possible via a direct Wi-Fi connection between [1] and [2]? If so, how do I set it up?

Comment: [HFS+ for Windows® 8/8.1 Free Edition](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows-free/) - note non commercial use only

Comment: [MacDrive 10](http://www.mediafour.com/software/macdrive/) - note 5 day trial available

Comment: No admin permissions on the windows machine, can only write to user directory

Comment: Why don't you ask your IT department to sort this out for you?

Answer (score 0):

macOS has built-in SMB (Windows-style) file sharing and a built-in ability to create Wi-Fi networks. So you can create a Wi-Fi network from the Mac and share the file via SMB, and then connect your Windows PC to that Wi-Fi network and then connect to the Mac via SMB in order to transfer the file.

Try this:

On the Mac:

1. System Preferences > Sharing > [√] Internet Sharing >
   Share your connection from: <anything>
   To computers using: [√] Wi-Fi.
   (Hopefully it won't refuse just because there's nothing hooked up to the "From" interface right now)
   Wi-Fi Options… (set a network name, channel, and security).
   If both your Mac and Windows PC support 5GHz Wi-Fi, use that; hopefully it'll allow you to use faster 802.11n or 802.11ac data rates.
2. System Preferences > Sharing > File Sharing
   …basically, set it up. Share the folder your 90 GiB file is in, set a user account that can access it, go under "Options…" and enable SMB sharing, etc.

Now, on the Windows box, join the Wi-Fi network you set up in step 1 above, and connect to the Mac using SMB with the username/password of the Mac account that has access to the shared folder.

Windows versions before Win10 don't have proper IETF ZeroConf (mDNS, Bonjour) support, so you'll probably have to look at your Mac to see what IP address it has on its Wi-Fi interface, and then tell your Windows PC to connect via SMB to that IP address, not the name.

Without knowing the exact specs of your Mac and Windows PC's Wi-Fi chipsets, it's hard to know what data rate you'll get for this Wi-Fi network, so it's hard to predict how long the copy will take. Worst case, it may be something you want to set up at the end of the day and leave running overnight.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is how to transfer files from an HFS+ USB disk then http://www.catacombae.org/hfsexplorer/ may work. It says it reads HFS+ drives.

Nice thing is that it is java. You can run it without installing if you want.